# Beginner in Elixir : parse CSV file

Tags: csv, elixir

Hello I'm a beginner in Elixir and I want to parse and stock a CSV file in an Elixir object.

But it's display that:

```elixir
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in anonymous fn/1 in Siren.parseCSV/0    
    
    The following arguments were given to anonymous fn/1 in Siren.parseCSV/0:
    
        # 1
        ["41", "5", "59", "N", "80", "39", "0", "W", "Youngstown", "OH"]
    
    anonymous fn/1 in Siren.parseCSV/0
    (elixir 1.10.3) lib/stream.ex:482: anonymous fn/4 in Stream.filter/2
    (elixir 1.10.3) lib/stream.ex:1449: Stream.do_element_resource/6
    (elixir 1.10.3) lib/stream.ex:1609: Enumerable.Stream.do_each/4
    (elixir 1.10.3) lib/enum.ex:959: Enum.find/3
    (mix 1.10.3) lib/mix/task.ex:330: Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix 1.10.3) lib/mix/cli.ex:82: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
```

Here my code:

```elixir
defmodule Siren do
  def parseCSV do
    IO.puts("Let's parse CSV file...")
    File.stream!("../name.csv")
    |> Stream.map(&String.trim(&1))
    |> Stream.map(&String.split(&1, ","))
    |> Stream.filter(fn
      ["LatD" | _] -> false
    end)
    |> Enum.find(fn State -> String
      [LatD, LatM, LatS, NS, LonD, LonM, LonS, EW, City, State] ->
        IO.puts("find -> #{State}")
        true
    end)
  end
end
```

And the csv file:

```
LatD,LatM,LatS,NS,LonD,LonM,LonS,EW,City,State
41,5,59,N,80,39,0,W,Youngstown,OH
42,52,48,N,97,23,23,W,Yankton,SD
46,35,59,N,120,30,36,W,Yakima,WA
42,16,12,N,71,48,0,W,Worcester,MA
43,37,48,N,89,46,11,W,WisconsinDells,WI
36,5,59,N,80,15,0,W,Winston-Salem,NC
49,52,48,N,97,9,0,W,Winnipeg,MB
39,11,23,N,78,9,36,W,Winchester,VA
34,14,24,N,77,55,11,W,Wilmington,NC
39,45,0,N,75,33,0,W,Wilmington,DE
48,9,0,N,103,37,12,W,Williston,ND
41,15,0,N,77,0,0,W,Williamsport,PA
37,40,48,N,82,16,47,W,Williamson,WV
33,54,0,N,98,29,23,W,WichitaFalls,TX
37,41,23,N,97,20,23,W,Wichita,KS
40,4,11,N,80,43,12,W,Wheeling,WV
26,43,11,N,80,3,0,W,WestPalmBeach,FL
47,25,11,N,120,19,11,W,Wenatchee,WA
41,25,11,N,122,23,23,W,Weed,CA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is here:

```rb
|> Stream.filter(fn
  ["LatD" | _] -> false
end)
```

all the lines should pass this and the only first one matches the given clauses. This would fix the issue

```rb
|> Stream.filter(fn
  ["LatD" | _] -> false
  _ -> true
end)
```

or

```rb
|> Stream.reject(&match?(["LatD" | _], &1))
```

---

`Enum.find(fn State -> String` after looks unclear and would be surely the next issue. I failed to understand what have you tried to achieve here.

---

The general advice would be: don’t reinvent the wheel and use [`NimbleCSV`](https://hexdocs.pm/nimble_csv) written by José Valim to parse CSVs, because there are lot of corner cases (like commas inside quotes in any field etc,) handled properly in the aforementioned library.

Comment: Thanks you Aleksei Matiushkin. I'm beginning to understand Elixir step by step :-). Indeed I saw NimbleCSV but to begin I'd like to practice with this little type of exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Aleksei Matiushkin gave you the right answer but also you have this function:

```
fn
  State -> 
    String
  [LatD, LatM, LatS, NS, LonD, LonM, LonS, EW, City, State] ->
    IO.puts("find -> #{State}")
    true
end
```

It accepts two possible values, either `State` which is an atom, or a list of 10 specific atoms.

What you want to do is use variables, and variables in Elixir start with a lowercase letter or an underscore if it has to be ignored.

```
fn
  state -> 
    String
  [latd, latm, lats, ns, lond, lonm, lons, ew, city, state] ->
    IO.puts("find -> #{state}")
    true
end
```

But in this case, the first clause of the function will always match anything because it acts like a catch-all clause.

What you probably want is:

```
fn
  [_latd, _latm, _lats, _ns, _lond, _lonm, _lons, _ew, _city, state] ->
    IO.puts("find -> #{state}")
    # here decide if you want to return true or false, 
    # for instance `state == NC`
    true
end
```

Comment: Sorry, indeed this part of my code wasn't achieve even for my brain... But I'm gonna move on with your advices, thanks lud.